# Unable to convert dates - LocalDate minus one day

Tags: java, date, java-11, localdate

I have a problem with the dates and their passage from Date to LocalDate, mainly the error is with the dates that have the year 1700.
I have tried two different dates and whenever the year is 1700, it puts me one day less.

```
Date dto = ...;
Instant inst = dto.toInstant();         
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(inst, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Date dto It is a variable that retrieves the date of a query. But the method only gets dto variable as input parameter.

```
Tue Dec 14 00:00:00 CET 1700 -> Date
1700-12-13T23:00:00Z -> Instant
1700-12-13 -> LocalDate

Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1994 -> Date
1993-12-31T23:00:00Z -> Instant
1994-01-01 -> LocalDate
```

I use:

```
jackson.time-zone: ${TZ:Europe/Madrid}
```

What is the problem with this year?

Comment: Where did you get that `Date dto` from? It might be whatever has produced that `dto` that has a problem.

Comment: @Sweeper It is a variable that retrieves the date of a query. But the method only gets the Date dto variable.

Comment: What does `ZoneId.systemDefault()` yield? Possibly you should use `ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")` instead so that things agree.

Comment: What do you mean "date of a query"? I'm pretty sure there are no computers in 1700... Do you mean that the date is a column of a database table? If so, what kind of database is it? How about directly storing `LocalDate`s and stop using `Date`s, which are *very* bad?

Comment: My Java believes that Madrid was at offset -00:14:44 from GMT back then. So `1700-12-13T23:00:00Z` (UTC) corresponds to `1700-12-13T22:45:16-00:14:44[Europe/Madrid]`, which explains why you got `1700-12-13` as `LocalDate`.

Comment: And it’s very credible that a `Date` that was supposed to hold 14 December 1700 has an incorrect instant in it so that the `Instant` objects gets wrong. `Date` is buggy when it comes to dates before year 1900. As @Sweeper said, if there is any way you can get rid of it, do.

Answer (score 3):

This is because whoever produced that `Date` and `ZoneId.systemDefault()` have different opinions on what Madrid's offset is from UTC, back in 1700.

Whoever produced that `Date` mistakenly thinks that Madrid is UTC+1 back in 1700-12-14, so it produced a `Date` that represents the midnight of 1700-12-14 in the zone UTC+1 ("CET"):

```
Tue Dec 14 00:00:00 CET 1700
```

This has a corresponding `Instant`, because we can pinpoint a certain point in time using this information. This is what `toInstant` gives you. `Instant.toString` always displays in UTC (more specifically ISO 8601), so you see:

```
1700-12-13T23:00:00Z
```

1700-12-14T00:00:00+01:00 is indeed the same point in time as 1700-12-13T23:00:00Z.

When you do `LocalDate.ofInstant`, you use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. `ZoneId.systemDefault()` thinks that Madrid had the offset of UTC-0:14:44. This is because Madrid had been observing [Local Mean Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html), and [did not standardise timezones until the 1900s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Spain#Standard_time_adoption).

Therefore, `LocalDate.ofInstant` subtracts 14 minutes and 44 seconds from 1700-12-13T23:00:00 to compute what the date would be at offset -0:14:44, and lo and behold, it is still 1700-12-13.

I would recommend that you not to use `Date` if possible. If what you are doing is related to time at all, you should work with `LocalDate`s directly.