# Converting from java.time.LocalDate to java.util.Date results in incorrect timestamp in Asia/Kolkata time zone

Tags: java, java-time

While converting `java.time.LocalDate` object into `java.util.Date` object, it works fine for  LocalDate > 1900-01-02 when system timezone is set to `Asia/Kolkata` / `IST`.

But for LocalDate <= 1900-01-01, it results in an offset 8 minutes and 50 seconds.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
Instant i1 = LocalDate.of(1900,1, 1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Instant i2 = LocalDate.of(1900,1, 2).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();

System.out.println(Date.from(i1));
System.out.println(Date.from(i2));
```

Output:

```
Mon Jan 01 00:08:50 IST 1900
Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 IST 1900
```

One can notice `08:50` for minutes and seconds for 1st of Jan, where as it's correctly set as `00:00` for 2nd Jan. It seems like it has something to do with 1st Jan, 1900 in IST falls on earlier year in UTC i.e. 31st Dec, 1899.

According to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india, the country has officially observed India Standard Time (IST) since 1947. However, the UTC+5:30 offset has been used as the local standard time in India since 1906. But surprisingly, it's working correctly for any Dates where year is 1900 in UTC.

Is there a way to convert 1900-01-01 LocalDate correctly into Date when time zone is set to `Asia/Kolkata` / `IST`?

Comment: This seems to be related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061577. Is there a workaround to convert LocalDate to Date correctly?

Comment: Generally speaking, time zone data gets wonky in the way past. Not only do we have limited specific information, what is available is often not encoded correctly or not used for some reason (some devices might ship with limited data cut off before a certain point to conserve storage/memory/processing time). I wouldn't expect any of this to work correctly. Is this an actual problem for your application or just a curiosity that you stumbled over?

Comment: It's an actual problem as we use 1900-01-01 as universe start date which is required to be converted to Date object in one of the workflows.

Comment: ***Why*** are you trying to convert to `Date`? Why can't you do everything in `java.time`? From [my past experience](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72347528/5133585), `java.util.Date` have very different ideas about historical timezones compared to the `java.time` APIs.I'd recommend you to stop using `java.util.Date` in the first place.

Comment: If you are using 1901-01-01 as an epoch reference, why does your code invoke the JVM’s current default time zone? Speaking of which, you never specified the time zone of your epoch reference. Are you counting time from first moment of January 1, 1900 as seen in UTC, or as seen in `Asia/Kolkata` time zone, or as seen in some other time zone?

Comment: You should post details and clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: After some investigation, I feel this is just like the linked answer in my previous comment. `TimeZone` and `ZoneId` disagree about the offset of `Asia/Kolkata` at `i1`. See the results of `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata").getOffset(i1.toEpochMilli())` and `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").getRules().getOffset(i1).getTotalSeconds() * 1000`, and also those for `i2`.

Comment: It seems like the old `TimeZone` just treats everything before 1900-01-01 midnight UTC as using modern standardised timezones, while everything after that point seem to agrees with java.time. In any case, *just don't use `Date`.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to convert dates - LocalDate minus one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72347528/unable-to-convert-dates-localdate-minus-one-day)

Comment: If it’s any consolation, you are getting a `Date` representing the correct point in time. It just prints wrong when you do `System.out.println()` thereby invoking its `toString` method.

Comment: @sweeper, yes, not using `Date` would be ideal, but there are APIs which accept `Date` and thus we need to convert to `Date` until those APIs are migrated to use `java.time.*` classes.
@OleV.V. thanks for the reference, it was helpful. Also, I agree on `toString` is little misleading as it tries to print in local time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through online resources, I stumbled upon [JDK-8061577](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061577) which explains the behavior. It's because `java.util.Calendar` supports `Julian-Gregorian` calendar where as newer `java.time.*` classes support `ISO 8601` calendar (i.e. `Proleptic-Gregorian` calendar). As calendars used are different, there can be differences that are observed while converting from one type to another based on calendar rules.

Luckily, Calendar builder allows setting calendar type to ISO 8601 which can be used as a workaround. So, following code snippet worked for us:

```
Date date = new Calendar.Builder().setCalendarType("iso8601")
                .setDate(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue() - 1, localDate.getDayOfMonth())
                .build()
                .getTime();
```