# Why does the LocalDateTime conversion to java.util.Date is shifting for very old date?

Tags: java, java-time, java.util.date

I am having trouble with converting old dates from java.time.LocalDateTime to java.util.Date

I tried a lot of variation and it still has the same shifted dates. I would assume that it is some weird calendar performed but it is failing.

Date to parse `1800-01-01 00:00:00`

I used a very simple convert function.

`Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());`

| TimeZone | a.Converted via SimpleDateFormat | b.Converted via DateFormatter to LocalDateTime to java.util.Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Asia/Tokyo | 1800-01-01 00:00:00 JST | 1799-12-31 23:41:01 JST |
| Europe/Brussels | 1800-01-01 00:00:00 CET | 1800-01-01 00:04:30 CET |
| Australia/Sydney | 1800-01-01 00:00:00 AEST | 1799-12-31 23:55:08 AEST |
| UTC | 1800-01-01 00:00:00 UTC | 1800-01-01 00:00:00 UTC |

a. Convert String to java.util.Date via SimpleDateFormat

b. Convert String to java.time.LocalDatetime via DateFormatter, then convert it to java.util.Date

Now I see it only works for the UTC timezone, I cannot just change the software timezone as it will mess with the others. Anyone know any other way to convert a java.time.LocalDateTime to java.util.Date for an old day?

`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

===== following is added after sweeper's answer to illustrate it is not for all ====

The curious thing is it only happens to really old dates, it does not happen to 1900-01-01 00:00:00 but have not check yet at which point the trouble started. I was thinking that maybe because of and adjustment / change at some point in 18XX year.

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo").getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.parse("1800-01-01T00:00:00")));
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo").getOffset(format1.parse("1800-01-01T00:00:00").getTime()));
        
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo").getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.parse("1900-01-01T00:00:00")));
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo").getOffset(format2.parse("1900-01-01T00:00:00").getTime()));
```

Results to

```
+09:18:59
32400000
+09:00
32400000
```

Comment: @Sweeper yes, correct. I fixed the spacing to make the comment more clearer

Comment: Have you got a very good reason for needing an old-fashioned `java.util.Date`, like for a legacy API that you cannot upgrade? Otherwise you should simply avoid that old class. And `TimeZone` and `SimpleDateFormat`. java.time, the modern date and time API to which `LocalDateTime` belongs, gives you all the functionality you wish for.

Comment: @OleV.V. It is for a bridge type approach for migrating from java.util to the new java.time, not all codes can be modified at once so as an intermediate solution.

Comment: Then I know exactly what you are talking about. Thanks for context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72347528/5133585), the old API disagrees with `ZoneId.systemDefault()` about what offsets those locations should be at on the date 1800-01-01.

You can see this in action:

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo").getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.parse("1800-01-01T00:00:00")));
var format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo").getOffset(format.parse("1800-01-01T00:00:00").getTime()));
```

Output:

```
+09:18:59
32400000
```

As said in the linked post, +09:18:59 is the [Local Mean Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html) in Japan, and 32400000ms is exactly 9 hours. This is because [the old APIs don't support Local Mean Time](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6281408?jql=text%20%7E%20%22local%20mean%20time%22). Note that [Japan standardised their timezones in 1888](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Standard_Time#History), which explains why the outputs from the two APIs are consistent for 1900-01-01.

So `ZoneId` thinks the offset of Asia/Tokyo is 18 minutes and 59 seconds more than what `TimeZone` (which is used by `SimpleSateFormat` and `Date.toString` and so on) thinks it is.

This is exactly why there is a "shift" in the output. `ldt.atZone(...)` generates

```
1800-01-01T00:00:00+09:18:59
```

and `toInstant` turns this into an instant.

Assuming you are using `Date.toString` or some other old API that uses `TimeZone` to generate the string, the old API would think this instant is at +09:00:00 instead! What is the above date at +09:00:00? Well, just subtract the 18 minutes and 59 seconds (just like how you would subtract 9 hours to convert a UTC+9 date to UTC+0)!

And that's how you get:

```
1799-12-31 23:41:01
```

---

As for solutions, there really is nothing wrong with the "shifted" `Date` that you got. If you just convert it back to a `ZonedDateTime` and format it with `DateTimeFormatter` for display, everything should work as normal. In fact, if you can, consider not converting to `Date` at all, and use `Instant`s instead.

If you cannot do that, I would suggest that you should not mix the two APIs.

Comment: I think the offset may be odd but why does the error only happens on old dates like 1900-01-01 00:00:00 it is ok. I will add that point to the question. I was not able to pin point exactly what date it started happening, before I assumed it was because of Julian to Gregorian Calendar switch but it does not happen in UTC. I think your answer is still applicable but I had to dig deeper.

Comment: See my update on the question, did you see diff between 1800 and 1900? so it is not always disagree, now wondering why it disagree at old date? not sure when it started, do you have some links like documentation

Comment: @Nap it seems like `Date` does not know about local mean times, so they would start agreeing when Japan (or whatever timezone you’re working with) started to standardise their timezones. I guess in this case they did it before 1900, but after 1800.

Comment: @Nap I have added a bug report about `TimeZone` not supporting local mean time. They won't fix it because of compatibility.